# Right() function in Access VBA

Tags: string, function, ms-access, vba

Is there a function that would return a certain value if the 8th character from the right equals a specific value?

I want it to return a specific text string if there is a "P" in the position 8 places before the end of the string.  I thought the Right() function would work, but it obviously does not just look for that one specific value.

This is what I tentatively have that doesn't work correctly:

```
ElseIf Right(rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo], 8) = "P" Then
sAdditionalText = "<Font face='Calibri'>" _
& "Please work with Purchasing to make the necessary corrections. <BR><BR>" _
& "<b>Please be advised that the funds from this check will remain as a charge against the FOAPALs utilized in the transaction until this matter is resolved.</b> <br><br>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Right` returns all 8 characters, not only the 8th character.

You can solve this in several ways:

1. Use `LIKE` and `Right` to test for a specific first character:

   ```vb
   ElseIf Right(rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo], 8) LIKE "P*" Then
   ```
2. Use a combination of `Left` and `Right` to select that specific character:

   ```vb
   ElseIf Left(Right(rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo], 8),1) = "P" Then
   ```
3. Use `StrReverse` and `Mid` to select that specific character:

   ```vb
   ElseIf Mid(StrReverse(rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo]), 8, 1) = "P" Then
   ```
4. Use `Mid` and `Len` to select a specific character (will error on strings with less than 8 characters)

   ```vb
   ElseIf(Mid(rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo], Len(rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo])-7, 1) = "P" Then
   ```
5. Use `Like` only to test for a character at a specific position

   ```vb
   ElseIf rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo] LIKE "*P???????" Then '7 questionmarks
   ```

Comment: I imagine the options that match a character at a given position will perform better than the solutions based on StrReverse / LIKE, if performance matters.